Example for SVM and Kfold
I want some examples for SVM and when do we use it and use Kfold or it's not the same.

Support Vector Machine (SVM)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
# Create and train the SVM model
svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear')  # You can choose different kernels like 'poly', 'rbf'
svm_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Make predictions
y_pred_svm = svm_model.predict(X_test)
IN Last  : ensambling
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('diabetics.csv')
df.head()
X=df.drop('outcome',axis=1)
print(X.shape)
y=df['outcome']
print(y.shape)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
#create new a knn model
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

#create a dictionary of all values we want to test for n_neighbors
params_knn = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 25)}
#use gridsearch to test all values for n_neighbors
knn_gs = GridSearchCV(knn, params_knn, cv=5)
#fit model to training data
knn_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

knn_best = knn_gs.best_estimator_
#check best n_neigbors value
print(knn_gs.best_params_)


#####################################################
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#create a new random forest classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
#create a dictionary of all values we want to test for n_estimators
params_rf = {'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200]}
#use gridsearch to test all values for n_estimators
rf_gs = GridSearchCV(rf, params_rf, cv=5)
#fit model to training data
rf_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

#save best model
rf_best = rf_gs.best_estimator_
#check best n_estimators value

print(rf_gs.best_params_)

#####################################################
from sklearn import svm
svm =svm.SVC(kernel="rbf")
svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Knn ',knn_best.score(X_test, y_test))
print('RF ',rf_best.score(X_test, y_test))
print('SVM ',svm.score(X_test, y_test))
####################################################
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
#create a dictionary of our models
estimators=[('knn', knn_best), ('rf', rf_best), ('svm', svm)]
#create our voting classifier, inputting our models
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
#fit model to training data
ensemble.fit(X_train, y_train)
#test our model on the test data
ensemble.score(X_test, y_test)

=> KFLOD cross Vaildtaion
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# Prepare the data
X = data.drop('outcome', axis=1)
y = data['outcome']

# Define the k-fold cross-validation
k = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None, shuffle=True)

# Perform k-fold cross-validation
for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X):
# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

# Print the shapes of the training and testing sets (optional)
print(f'Train indices: {train_index}, Test indices: {test_index}')
print(f'X_train shape: {X_train.shape}, X_test shape: {X_test.shape}')
print(f'y_train shape: {y_train.shape}, y_test shape: {y_test.shape}')


############################################################################

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
# Prepare the data
X = data.drop('outcome', axis=1)
y = data['outcome']
# Initialize the RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
# Define the k-fold cross-validation
k = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None, shuffle=True)
# List to store accuracy for each fold
acclist = []
# Perform k-fold cross-validation
for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X):
# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
# Fit the model on the training data
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Make predictions on the test data
predictions = rf.predict(X_test)
# Calculate the confusion matrix and accuracy
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
# Append the accuracy to the list
acclist.append(acc)
# Print the list of accuracies
print("Accuracies for each fold:", acclist)
# Calculate and print the average accuracy
average_acc = sum(acclist) / k
print("Average accuracy:", average_acc)


#imputing missing values
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
#mean, median, or most_frequent
#ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent'), [1,2])], remainder='passthrough')
#data = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(data))
#data
imputer.fit(data.iloc[:, 1:3])
data.iloc[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(data.iloc[:, 1:3])
print the dataset
data
